# Django No module name found although I already pip install

Tags: django

I am using this for push notification and it is okay on my localhost.

https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications

But when I deploy to server,
I did

```
pip install django-push-notifications
```

But in my settings.py, when I add this, it crash and it say server configuration is wrong. How shall I do?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'push_notifications'
)
```

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: It just give The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: sounds like an import error..perhaps it can't find that library due to path differences.  your server should have log files that give more info.  try looking in /var/log or try running the same command the server does to start the application

Comment: yes indeed. It is ImportError: No module named push-notifications
But I have already checked with "pip freeze" and it is already there.

Comment: ok, your server config is probably using a different virtual environment than the one you're installing the package in.  see if you can find out the path to python / pip the server is using.  one way to do this if you dont have more info on the server config is to 
>>> import os
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getfile(os)

Comment: Post your config and we will tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Could you find the solution to this?